# Read the output in an expect file in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcl, expect

I am trying to read the output of a command and set it in a variable and then send like a text to a file:

```
expect "~]#" { send "readlink some/link\r" }
set CCM_BUILD $expect_out(buffer)
send_log "CCM: $CCM_BUILD"
```

but what I get in my files is:

```
can't read "expect_out(buffer)": no such variable
    while executing
"set CCM_BUILD $expect_out(buffer)"
    (file "../common/get_build.exp" line 20)^M
```

I tried different things nothing I found seemed to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: @glennjackman please take a look at this I know you are a pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The var `$expect_out(buffer)` would not be updated until you call `expect`. So try like this:

```
expect "~]#" { send "readlink some/link\r" }
expect "~]#" { set CCM_BUILD $expect_out(buffer) }
```

Comment: no it gives me this [[?1034h-bash-4.1$ can't read "CCM_BUILD": no such variable
    while executing
"send_log $CCM_BUILD"
    (file "../common/get_build.exp" line 26)^M

Comment: sounds like your _prompt_ string does not really include `"~]#"`.